# How to divide string like this into items in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, string-parsing, split

Here is the string:

```
format db "this is string a", 0, 0Ah
```

And I am trying to split it into this:

```
format
db
"this is string a"
0
0Ah
```

Is there any way can do this in python 2.7?

Thank you!

Comment: is this a fixed string?

Comment: @Charlesliam Hi, basically I am using Python to parse the assembly code, and I have to deal with stuff like this in parsing the data section of assembly code..

Comment: do you need those quotes to remain on the third string?

Comment: @roippi No, not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `shlex.split`:

```
s = 'format db "this is string a", 0, 0Ah'

import shlex

shlex.split(s)
Out[18]: ['format', 'db', 'this is string a,', '0,', '0Ah']
```

Your grammar is a little wonky with the trailing commas, but you can pretty safely `rstrip` that out:

```
[x.rstrip(',') for x in shlex.split(s)]
Out[20]: ['format', 'db', 'this is string a', '0', '0Ah']
```

Comment: shlex.split is much better than re.split

Comment: I agree, see how ugly my answer is.

Comment: groovy! Thank you roippi!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there will be more elegant answers, but this'll work and preserve the quotes:

```
def parse(s):
    s = s.split(', ')
    stack = []
    new = ''
    inQuotes = False
    for char in s[0]:
        if char == '"':
            inQuotes = True
        if not inQuotes:
            if not char == ' ':
                new += char
            else:
                stack.append(new)
                new = ''
        else:
            new += char
    stack.append(new)
    del s[0]
    stack.extend(s)
    return stack

>>> s = 'format db "this is string a", 0, 0Ah'
>>> parse(s)
['format', 'db', '"this is string a"', '0', '0Ah']
```

Answer (score 1):

A regex solution:

```
import re

data = 'format db "this is string a", 0, 0Ah'
s = re.findall(r'''(?:[^ '"]+|'(?:[^']|\\.)*'|"(?:[^']|\\.)*")+''', data)
print [x.rstrip(',') for x in s]
```

output:

```
['format', 'db', '"this is string a"', '0', '0Ah']
```

Comment: the output is one line?